# How to validate JSON request matched with model/dto entity?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple problem in Spring/JPA. Supposedly, I have this format of request:

**model/BillDto.java**

```
public class BillDto {
    private String desc;
    private Long id;
    private Integer amount;
    
    public BillDto(String desc, long id, int amount) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

or as this json format

```
{
    "desc": "String",
    "id": 0,
    "amount": 0
}
```

And this is the controller

**controller/BillController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody BillDto billDto) {
    billService.create(billDto); // some service to execute
}
```

However when I accidentally request with wrong format, the generated SQL won't execute, hence it returns 500 code. For example,

```
{
    "desc": "String",
    "id": 0
}
```

How do I handle this error in shortest lines of codes? How do I validate the json request to match the model/dto before passing it to service?

Comment: What do you mean by handle? Avoid getting 500 code even the submitted request (JSON) is not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`@Valid`** annotation to the BillDto parameter annotated with @RequestBody. This will tell Spring to process validation before making an actual method call. In case validation fails, Spring will throw a `MethodArgument NotValidException` which, by default, will return a 400 (Bad Request) response.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@Valid @RequestBody BillDto billDto) {
    billService.create(billDto); // some service to execute
}
```

In POST or PUT requests, when we pass JSON payload, Spring automatically converts it into a Java object and now it can validate the resulting object.

Comment: You also need to mark your DTO with the proper validation annotations.